# Dropdowns not sizing correctly

Tags: css

I have a navigation bar that contains elements, two of them are dropdown menus. I fixed the size of the elements on the navigation bar, but Im not able to do it on the elements that drop down. When the drop down comes down it is too wide, but when I hover over the elements, part of only the "fixed width" I specified is highlighted, and the rest isn't. I want them all to be 100px with no extra space on the side, how can I do that?

Code:

```css
.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.topnav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.topnav li {
  float: left;
}

.topnav li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100px;
}

.topnav li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #111;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.topnav .dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.topnav .dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Products</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Computers</a>
        <a href="#">Tablets</a>
        <a href="#">Cell Phones</a>
        <a href="#">Wearable Technologies</a>
        <a href="#">Accessories</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Brands</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Apple</a>
        <a href="#">Samsung</a>
        <a href="#">Lenovo</a>
        <a href="#">Dell</a>
        <a href="#">HP</a>
        <a href="#">Sony</a>
        <a href="#">Panasonic</a>
        <a href="#">Motorola</a>
        <a href="#">HTC</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="deals.html">Deals</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/29r9d18a/22/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `min-width: 160px` from your `.dropdown-content` CSS class.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know how I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Change `min-width` of this one `.dropdown-content` and add `max-width: 100px;` also add `word-break: break-word;`.

Like this

```
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: auto;
  max-width: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  word-break: break-word;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

**Here is the working code.**

```css
.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.topnav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-padding-start: 0;
}

.topnav li {
  float: left;
}

.topnav li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100px;
}

.topnav li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #111;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: auto;
  max-width: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  word-break: break-word;
  z-index: 1;
}

.topnav .dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.topnav .dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Products</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Computers</a>
        <a href="#">Tablets</a>
        <a href="#">Cell Phones</a>
        <a href="#">Wearable Technologies</a>
        <a href="#">Accessories</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Brands</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Apple</a>
        <a href="#">Samsung</a>
        <a href="#">Lenovo</a>
        <a href="#">Dell</a>
        <a href="#">HP</a>
        <a href="#">Sony</a>
        <a href="#">Panasonic</a>
        <a href="#">Motorola</a>
        <a href="#">HTC</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="deals.html">Deals</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```